# Spanwise lift distribution units

Tags: wing, lift

I was recently reading NASA/Boeing’s report on the Transonic Truss Braced Wing (the SUGAR IV final report), and noticed that when they graph the spanload for the design they graph lift coefficient multiplied by normalised chord against span, rather than just lift coefficient against span. I guess this is a pretty good proxy for circulation minus a few constants.
My question is, I’ve seen this described elsewhere as a ‘load distribution’ rather than a ‘lift distribution’, what is the difference, and if I were to graph lift coefficient against span would this not be a spanload (unless I have a rectangular wing) since it isn’t a good expression of circulation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2D (sectional) lift coefficient is usually abbreviated $c_l$, and the sectional lift is usually $l$.  The former is dimensionless, the latter has units of force/length.

$l=c_l\,q\,c$

For 3D, we use $C_L$ and $L$

$L=C_L\,q\,S$

When integrating from root to tip along a wing, we can write

$S=2*\int_0^{b/2} c(y)\,dy$

Where the 2 is to capture both halves of the wing, and $b$ is the wingspan.  I have written $c(y)$ to emphasize that the chord is a function of the span -- i.e. the wing is tapered.

We might then define $\bar{c}$ such that:

$S=b\,\bar{c}$

We can also write (for a symmetrical condition)

$L=2*\int_0^{b/2} l(y)\,dy$

Here $l(y)$ is the load distribution.  The distribution of sectional force that we integrate to get the total lift.  This is what matters for induced drag minimization.

Substituting the definition of $l$ above (and pulling out the dynamic pressure)...

$L=q\,2*\int_0^{b/2} c_l\,c(y)\,dy$

Here you can see where the practice of plotting $c_l\,c$ comes from.  It is proportional to the local load distribution.

Applying the definition of $C_L$

$C_L=\frac{2}{S}*\int_0^{b/2} c_l\,c(y)\,dy$

Where $S$ can be written...

$C_L=\frac{2}{b\,\bar{c}}*\int_0^{b/2} c_l\,c(y)\,dy$

If you pull the $\bar{c}$ back in, you get

$C_L=\frac{2}{b}*\int_0^{b/2} \frac{c_l\,c(y)}{\bar{c}}dy$

Which shows us that this term:

$\frac{c_l\,c(y)}{\bar{c}}$

Is proportional to the load distribution, but it is scaled to be similar to lift coefficient.

When you compare plotting the above with just $c_l$, you see that the difference is in the weighting by the local chord.

Consider a wing with a lot of taper.  Imagine that it somehow has the same lift coefficient everywhere.  The root section with large chord contributes more to the load than does the tip section with a short chord.

Both plots are useful.

$\frac{c_l\,c(y)}{\bar{c}}$

Is good for comparing to an elliptical shape to understand how good the induced drag will be for the wing.  It is also important for the starting point of structural calculations.

$c_l(y)$

Is good for considering how 'close' you are to stall.  It shows how 'hard' the local airfoil is working.

A wing with uniform load distribution ($l(y)$), but with lots of taper will have a $c_l(y)$ that increases sharply at the tips.  That is a wing that is prone to tip stall.

Comment: Thanks! So if I want a wing to follow a particular lift distribution for drag minimisation purposes, I need to plot c_l(y)*c(y)/cbar rather than just purely cl(y).

Comment: @AlastairWyllie That is correct.  They will look the same if c(y) is constant, but otherwise, you need to keep those in there.